# How to change the opacity of an image in Pygame

Tags: python, image-processing, pygame, python-imaging-library, png

I try to display an image in Pygame but I want to change the opacity of it.
The game is a card memory game, and for the home page background I want to be a dark screen containing some cards, with different positions, sizes, rotation angles, and **opacity**.
The image is a simple card with a question mark, meaning the image on the other side is a mystery.
[image]
The image actual image is 35x70.

Every time I want change the opacity I cannot do that.

I tried more ways:

```
import pygame 
from PIL import Image as Img
pygame.init()


class Image:
    def __init__(self,image_path : str, size : tuple, rotation_angle : int, position : list, screen : object, opacity = 255) -> None:
        self.size = size 
        self.rotation_angle = rotation_angle
        self.position = position
        self.screen = screen 
        self.opacity = opacity

        # initiate image & its properties

        # Initiate the image and convert it.
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image_path).convert_alpha() 
        self.get_position()
        #if self.rotation_angle:
            #self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image,self.rotation_angle)



    """ Set the position. The position could be a string or int. If the pos[0] or pos[1] is a 
    string, the only possible it that the horizontal/vertical pos is in the center otherwise
    it should be an integer with the position """

    def get_position(self) -> None:

        if self.position[0] == "center":
            self.position[0] = self.screen.get_size()[0] // 2 - self.image.get_size()[0] // 2
        if self.position[0] != "center":
            self.position[0] = int(self.position[0])


        if self.position[1] == "center":
            self.position[1] = self.screen.get_size()[1] // 2 - self.image.get_size()[1] // 2
        if self.position[1] != "center":
            self.position[1] = int(self.position[1])

    
    def display_image(self) -> None:
        self.image.set_alpha(self.opacity)
        self.screen.blit(self.image,self.position)
```

Every time I try this way I get some weird thing displayed. The half of image opacity seems to apply, but the other side opacity still remains 255.

I also tried with PIL, the image generated was good, the opacity applies overall image, but when I try to display it, the opacity remains 255.

Answer (score 0):

You can use set_alpha command. Here is the link
https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_alpha.

Just keep in mind the value is from 0 to 255. (255 is fully opaque and 0 is transparent)

```
self.image.set_alpha(opacity)
```